# replacing zsh with bash on non-root user

Tags: linux, bash, zsh

so after trying out all the terminals. I finally stuck over `hyper.js` and I configured zsh as default for root by

```
chsh -s /usr/bin/zsh root
```

And I get `zsh` when I login as `root`. But when I try it with using the same command and replacing the root with my `USER_NAME` it shows no error but I'm getting `bash` by default.. I loved `zsh` and I want it all over my users, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have experienced chsh not working in linuxes in the past.

I suggest `usermod -s` the rest of the syntax is the same as the `chsh` command.

If this still doesn't work, then you can manually change the path for your user's default shell in `/etc/passwd` - this will require root privileges.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanx this worked.. BTW also can you tell me what does this **Chsh** Command does....  Where else can I use it.

Comment: `usermod`? It mostly modifies user information in `/etc/passwd` and it can manipulate a users' groups. `chsh` is supposed to manage a users login shell by manipulating `/etc/passwd`, but for some reason it's behavior doesn't appear consistent on all *nixs.  Let me know if this answered your question.

Comment: Thanx for your replies..  It helped :)

Comment: I would appreciate you marking my answer as accepted if the information resolved your issue.  Have a nice day.